# How long after accepting tribute can I attack an enemy civ?

Tags: civilization-2

I entered diplomatic relations with the English and demanded they provide tribute. It was easy, I have a pretty tight grip on the world, I just happened to be a number of turns away from being near their home to take it over.

But now I want to attack them and it says my reputation would be damaged if I attack them so soon. Not that I'm too worried about my reputation, but I might as well keep it if I can.

How long do I have to wait after accepting tribute until I can attack these fools who dared to settle in my world without sacrificing my spotless reputation?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently "16 turns or so"

From Civilization 2 Manual, page 126

[image]

Comment: It makes you wonder what they mean by "or so"...

Comment: @mbomb007 I suspect that they wanted something like a wonder or government to be able to effect it. I know Eiffel Tower affects the penalty for breaking treaty, not aware of any effecting the length though.

Comment: It might check every 4 turns to see if tribute is still valid. So 13-16 if you time it right, similar to how changing civs works. I'll have to get in that situation again to confirm everything, but this looks promising. It's certainly Horse's Mouth, which is great. The question is if the cease fire is the only thing that stops it. I specifically see a box that says "we recently accepted tribute yada yada" and I suspect that is important. I'll test this out though.